# Property is not hiding the parent class property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a custom Image Control to modity the source proerty using this code.

```
public class StorageImage : Image
{

    [TypeConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    public new  ImageSource Source { get; set; }

}

public class CustomConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public static Func<string> GetFolderName;

        public override object ConvertFromInvariantString(string value)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return ImageSource.FromFile(Path.Combine(GetFolderName(), value));
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the Source property that i created is not hiding the parent property. However if i use a new property instead Source like this

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
    public ImageSource StorageSource { get; set; }
```

then everything works fine.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the images stored in the storage.

Comment: You said that using `[TypeConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]` makes everything work fine. Why don't you do that?

Comment: TypeConverter is working fine , the problem is if i use  public new  ImageSource Source { get; set; } then this property is not used instead the base property is used.

Comment: what base property look like. please share Image class

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande Base class is Xamarin Forms Image class.

Comment: @Kalp is that the same ImageSource that is used for this type

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande i did not understand ?

Comment: @Kalp is the `ImageSource` property is referring of the same type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178431/discussion-between-kalp-and-ameya-deshpande).